# How to force a JAXBException when marshalling for a JUnit test

Tags: jaxb

I haven't been able to find a way to force a JAXBException when marshalling for a JUnit test. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is my marshalling code:

```
   public String toXml() {
          log.debug("Entered toXml method");
    String result = null;
    try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Config.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(this, writer);
        result = writer.toString();
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
          log.error(e);
    }
          log.debug("Exiting toXml method");
    return result;
   }
```

Answer (score 6):

There are different ways to create a `JAXBException` during a `marshal` operation:

**1 - Marshal an Invalid Object**

You can generate a `JAXBException` during a marshal operation by marshalling an instance of a class that the `JAXBContext` isn't aware of (i.e. Take your example and use it to marshal an instance of `Foo`).  This will produce the following exception.

```java
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class forum13389277.Foo nor any of its super class is known to this context.
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getBeanInfo(JAXBContextImpl.java:594)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:482)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:315)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:244)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:95)
    at forum13272288.Demo.main(Demo.java:27)
```

**2 - Marshal to Invalid Output**

If you try to marshal to an invalid output such as an `OutputStream` that has been closed:

```java
    FileOutputStream closedStream = new FileOutputStream("src/foo.xml");
    closedStream.close();
    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(this, closedStream);
```

Then you will get a `MarshalException` which is a subclass of `JAXBException`.

```java
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.io.IOException: Stream Closed]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:320)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:244)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:95)
    at forum13272288.Demo.main(Demo.java:27)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:318)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.output.UTF8XmlOutput.flushBuffer(UTF8XmlOutput.java:413)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.output.UTF8XmlOutput.endDocument(UTF8XmlOutput.java:137)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.output.IndentingUTF8XmlOutput.endDocument(IndentingUTF8XmlOutput.java:165)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.endDocument(XMLSerializer.java:852)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.postwrite(MarshallerImpl.java:369)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:316)
    ... 3 more
```